# js заболкировать прокуртку (onmousewheel event passive) без warning в консоли

Tags: javascript

Если написать такой код:

```
document.querySelector('select[name=month]').onmousewheel = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

То в консоль получаю такую ошибку:

`Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952`

Намекая на то чтоб я делал "пасивную" не блокирующую оброботку события, чтоб увеличить скорость прокрутки. Чтоб я делал типа так:

`document.querySelector('select[name=month]').addEventListener('mousewheel', onmousewheel, {passive: true});`

Но дело в том что мне как раз таки нужно блочить прокрутку. И я не хочу в консоль ворнинги. Пример такого случая (код можно запустить, нужно крутить колесиком на `select`-е):

```js
document.querySelector('select[name=month]').onmousewheel =
document.querySelector('select[name=year]').onmousewheel = function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    const options = this.options;
    const newSelectIndex = options.selectedIndex
        + ((e.deltaY < 0) ? -1 : 1);

    if (options[newSelectIndex]) {
        options.selectedIndex = newSelectIndex;
    }
};
```

```html
<form style="text-align:center">
    <select name="month">
        <option value="1"> January</option>
        <option value="2"> February</option>
        <option value="3"> March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5"> May</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="6"> June</option>
        <option value="7"> July</option>
        <option value="8"> August</option>
        <option value="9"> September</option>
        <option value="10"> October</option>
        <option value="11"> November</option>
        <option value="12"> December</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year">
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Подскажите как блочить прокрутку без ворнингов. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ребята, извините, это на столько тупо))
Методом тыка выяснилось что нужно выставить просто `{passive: false}` тогда отдично работает `e.preventDefault();` и не ругается

```
document.querySelector('select[name=month]')
    .addEventListener('mousewheel', onmousewheel, {passive: false});
```

Всем большое спасибо!

Comment: Не за что :) :) :)